# How am I able to smoke at Heathrow during a 13-hour layover as a South African citizen? Can I exit passport control?

Tags: uk, transit, lhr, south-african-citizens, smoking

I am flying Virgin Atlantic from the USA back home to South Africa. I have a 13-hour layover at Heathrow airport. Will I be able to pass through passport control to be able to go smoke in the designated areas, and then return through security before my flight back to South Africa?

Comment: Do you have a valid US visa? this will determine if you can pass the passport control or not..

Comment: On a related note, doesn't Heathrow have these smoking cabins, like many European airports?

Comment: You could also bring nicotine gum or lozenges in case you can't smoke.

Comment: @DCTLib The English (and Welsh) law doesn't allow for them. Inside is inside.

Comment: From http://www.heathrowairport.com/heathrow-airport-guide/services-and-facilities/smoking-areas : Smoking is permitted in designated areas OUTSIDE the terminal building

Comment: If you are indeed allowed to pass immigration to get outside, do it _right at the exit of your first plane_. Do not choose the "transfer" lane, but go directly to immigration then out. Even as a citizen who can go freely into UK, in Heatrow I have been refused exit of the international area because my next plane was in **less than 6 hours** (as if it would take me 5 hours to get out and back in). You may be ok with 13 hours, but my way now is get out of the airport from the first plane, then only pass security back inside 1 hour before the next plane. Do not plan to do trips in and out easily.

Answer (score 15):

From the new rules that activated yesterday, these parts were **REMOVED** from the rules...

> you’re travelling from (or on part of a reasonable journey from)
>   Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the USA and have a valid visa for
>   that country
>
> you’re travelling from (or on part of a reasonable journey from)
>   Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the USA and it’s less than 6 months
>   since you last entered that country with a valid entry visa

**Visitor in Transit Strategy**:  You only need a valid visa for entry into the USA (Australia, etc). Being on the leg of a trip to/from the USA (Australia, etc) is now irrelevant.  The US visa, or any other **exemption document** listed in the rules, such as a valid common format Category D visa for entry to an EEA state or Switzerland is sufficient to qualify.

Source: http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2014/2702/pdfs/uksi_20142702_en.pdf

**Temporary Admission Strategy**:  Failing all of that, it is also perfectly acceptable to ask an Immigration Officer for a Temporary Admission.  There's paperwork, and they will take custody of your passport, but it's an avenue if all else fails. They do not have to give a TA if they don't want to, and they do not have to have a good reason for refusing.  However it does NOT count as a refusal that must be reported in subsequent applications.

Comment: (+1) Interesting, so it's now more-or-less like in the Schengen area?

Comment: That sounds like an awful lot of hassle to go through. Is sucking on a cancer stick really that important to you?

Comment: @Relaxed Astute comment. I like that. Indeed, they are trying to regularise to lots of Schengen rules (but not all).

Comment: @Shadur Probably not for a few hours, but the flight is 13 hours which is a really long time to go with out a cancer stick...

Comment: @Shadur: A 13-hour layover sandwiched between two 8+ hour flights? If that's not a good reason to suck on a cancer stick, you're probably not a smoker.